# WebStorm 11, Node-Express debugger does not collect data

Tags: node.js, debugging, express, webstorm

I'm trying to analyze my request object

```
app.post('/:path*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('foo'); // breakpoint 
}
```

When Debugger stops, it say "Collecting data..." but never shows any information. No matter if its local or global or whatever.

Comment: what Node.js version do you use?

Comment: I see:) you need to either downgrade Node or upgrade webStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm 11 doesn't support V8 that comes with Node6. [WEB-21192](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21192) is fixed in WebStorm 2016.1.*